# Load an image from the pc and set it to a label in QT

Tags: c++, image, qt, label

how can I load an image from a folder in my pc , and set it to a Label .
 I want to do this everytime I open my application window , that means everytime I choose a different image and I set it to the same Label .thank you .

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you are having a problem since you have not posted any code. Try this:

```
ui->imageLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image));
```

You might also want to see [this](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/29791-How-to-Load-Image-File-into-Desiger-Created-Qlabel), where someone asked a similar question.

From Qt docs:
http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlabel.html#pixmap-prop and 
http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qpixmap.html

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <QApplication>

#include <QPixmap>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QHBoxLayout>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   QApplication a(argc, argv);

   QString picName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(0, "Open Image", "/home/", 
   "Image Files (*.png *.jpg *.bmp)");

   QPixmap pic(picName);

   QLabel *label = new QLabel;
   label->setPixmap(pic);

   label->show();

   return a.exec();
}
```